# Pixi.js / Phaser.js with Phonegap FastCanvas plugin?

Tags: cordova, phaser-framework, pixi.js

[FastCanvas](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FastCanvas) is a solution for Phonegap/Cordova to get a faster canvas in Android, but it must be created with `FastCanvas.create();`

I would like to use Pixi.js (or Phaser.js which uses Pixi.js) , but these libraries create their own canvas element.

Has anybody ever combined these ?  Is there a way to make Pixi.js use FastCanvas?

Answer (score 0):

If this was a simple case of just replacing the canvas that is created with a call to `FastCanvas.create`then I'd say this would be quite trivial to support. But in looking at their documentation further it appears just a fraction of the Canvas API is implemented (purely image drawing) which would mean the insertion of a huge number of conditional checks through-out the code base, as well as a number of core features like Text and Debug simply not working. It's something we may consider for Phaser3 development next year, when we will focus on a more modular system, but I'm afraid to get this into Phaser2 you'll need to create your own fork and go through replacing calls and adding checks where needed.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I realize now that FastCanvas is not a full alternative for a canvas. I tried replacing the canvas in Phaser with FastCanvas and even fillRect is not supported. The solution of 'gles.js' looks very promising though, did you check that out ?  It's not officially released and seems more like a hobby project, but it offers blazing speed of the pixi demos even on my old Galaxy S with Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

For pixi.js on android 4.0 to 5.0+. If you would like to keep my point of view : " you need to use Crosswalk for android chromium webview. Better Crosswalk for pixi.js lib.